# Regular Expression to Match North American Phone Numbers Not Working

Tags: regex

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

The above is `regular expression` I have created for matching north-american phone number with and without parenthesis in code. But its not working, I don't seem to find the issue.

```
(180)-555-5555 --> Not Matching
180-555-5555 --> Matching
```

Some one help me understand why this is not matching? 
`'\(\d{3}\)'` is used for capture the parenthesis.

Comment: You miss single dash. `^(\(\d{3}\)-|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$`

Comment: Why am i down voted here? Is that anything wrong with the question i asked here? What is wrong with this community?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am just learner who wants to know more about a topic. Is that wrong? :)  i think whoever down voted this question are experts who rule the world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})?([.-]?)\d{3}\2\d{4}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rW3rR6/1)

Comment: Its is not working..This one worked fine ^(\(\d{3}\)-|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$

Comment: did you see the demo link I attached.

Comment: what's the problem with your regex is, it would match `(180)-555.5555` also. But mine would also match `-555-5555`. To avoid this type of matching, you need to use negative lookahead. https://regex101.com/r/rW3rR6/2

Comment: Wow Man.. i didn't notice that. Thanks .. It's really helpful.

Comment: This answer would be far more valuable with some pattern explanation. "_You may try this_" does very little to educate regex-illiterate researchers.